# Visual Studio Code not Opening in Desired Directory with `code .` Command

Tags: visual-studio-code, path

I'm experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code where, upon running the `code .` command in my terminal, the editor opens, but not in the directory I intend. Instead, it opens the `Microsoft VS Code\bin\code` directory. I've checked my system PATH, reinstalled Visual Studio Code, and ensured the correct directory is in the PATH, but the problem persists.

Does anyone have insights into what might be causing this behavior and how to resolve it?

Additional information:

- Operating System: Windows 11 23H2
- Visual Studio Code Version: 1.84.2

[image]

Comment: did you alias "code" to anything in your shell? is `code .` the exact and only contents of your commandline when you run it? does that happen no matter what the cwd is when you run that command?

Comment: @starball No, I haven't altered any shell commands, and 'code .' is the exact and only content of my command line. The issue persists no matter what the current working directory is.

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) any change if you uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: @starball When I type "Help" in the command palette, it's showing "No matching results," and nothing happens. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code, but the issue persists.

Comment: the command is called `Help: About`. Maybe you didn't start the command palette line with a `>`, which is necessary to put it in command mode.

Comment: @starball Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631

Comment: "**into your question post**". also, are you trying to run from WSL? and in what shell and what version of that shell are you running `code .`?

Comment: @starball My default terminal is PowerShell, and the version is **5.1.22621.2506**. I'm not using WSL to run VS Code.